# shapefile to a raster .tif file R

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, spatial, r-sf

I added a new variable to code the cells of my shape file, I want to save that file as a `.tif` and have all the information of my new variable. I saved it as a new `.shp` file and then use `shp2raster` function but I get and error.

```
beijing10<-sf::read_sf("Landuse/Beijing2010.shp")
beijing10<-mutate(beijing10,land=ifelse(CODE%in%c(41,42),"Cultivated Land","Unused Land"))
st_write(beijing10,"beijing2010new.shp")
shp2raster("beijing2010new.shp",column = "land")
```

error:
`Error in p$rasterize(nrow(r), ncol(r), as.vector(extent(r)), values, background) :  Not compatible with requested type: [type=character; target=double].`

I also try this but I don't get 2 clases.

```
r <- raster(ncol=180, nrow=180) #can take any value
extent(r) <- extent(beijing10)
rr<-rasterize(beijing10,r,'land')
writeRaster(rr,"beijing2.tif",options=c('TFW=YES'),'land')
```

Is there a another option to get the `.tif` file. Can someone help me to understand how does the transformation work and how should I add the right code so I don't need to use ArcMap do get the file. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal, reproducible, self-contained example

```
library(raster)
p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))
r <- raster(p, res=0.01)
p$land <- ifelse(p$ID_2 > 6, "Cultivated Land", "Unused Land")
```

The error occurs because you are trying to rasterize a character variable. That is not supported. You can use a factor, though

```
p$land <- as.factor(p$land)
r <- rasterize(p, r, "land")
r
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 73, 78, 5694  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
#extent     : 5.74414, 6.52414, 49.45162, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 1, 2  (min, max)
```